# Is Record Type not supported for some standard objects?

Tags: record-type

I can't create a record type (from Salesforce interface) for these standard objects: Attachment, OpportunityLineItem, Question and User). There is no link or button in the UI that allows it.

Does Salesforce provide record types for theses objects? Or am I missing something here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a couple of things here. First is that RecordTypes are generally used to "categorize" or "group" similar records where a distinction needs to be made between them for easy recognition. They can also be used for business process reasons (e.g. show/hide fields when a stage changes).

On the objects you've mentioned, such as Opportunity Line Item, it's a child of Opportunity which supports RecordTypes. Without the context of the Opportunity Record the Line Item is on, a record type would have no meaning. In essence, the OLI would inherit its RecordType from the Opportunity's RecordType. The same would apply to any kind of Attachment as it would be a child of the record it's attached to.

In the case of the User Object, we have Profiles, Groups and Roles as means of organizing and distinguishing different Users (not to mention User.Type). There's no need to apply RecordTypes to Users. In addition to a User's profile, they can also have an associated Contact Record which could have a RecordType applied to it if an organization desired to do that. The latter is always the case when we're referring to an external User which requires a Contact Record to exist before they can be created.